Google Apps Script - Export HTML form data with styling to PDF
I have an HTML form that saves to a Google Sheets database. I would like to know if it's possible to create a PDF file from the submitted data with the styling of the form.
Not sure if this is doable, so I'm asking for some insight. And if it is, I would appreciate some help getting it done!

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand create a PDF file from the submitted data with the styling of the form. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script, the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

This is a link to the form: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxJlHm3ySGF9grUHTw3SSwga9WTwysH5uUJ_MCENrt2hMaoawBJZhWovuoOrplNiy0/exec
I would like to have the form filled in and the data exported to a PDF when the "SUBMIT" button is clicked.

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your current script, the sample input and output situations you expect. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Currently that script takes data and saves it to a google sheet. I want the form to also make a PDF file with the filled in data. Does that make sense?

It depends on the styling of the form.

Unfortunately, you can't create a PDF response in real-time. However, you can create Google Docs and save them in real-time. and the convert that into a PDF.
Script to create Google Doc
const saveAsDocument = () => {
  const yourResponse = [['name', 'John']]; /* <=== Your response here */

  const doc = DocumentApp.create(`New Response`);

  body = doc.getBody();

  yourResponse.forEach( response => {
    body.appendParagraph(response[0] + ": " + response[1]);
  })
}

After every submission, you will create a Google Docs file.
You can create another script that will open the docs and save them in PDF format.

Hi lucepall! Thanks for clarifying that. I just tried the code you sent and tried testing it and I didn't see anything happen. Where are the docs going to be saved?

Hi, if you go to https://docs.google.com/ you will see every single document, You must need to find the one that starts with "Response ". Just remenber the step number 2, set a Trigger in order to run the script when the form is sumitted

If you run the code manually it will convert a document from the last response.

So I was looking in the wrong place but I just re-did everything and retried it. I checked on the execution of the trigger and there's nothing there. I copied and pasted the code you sent me under codge.gs  . Is that the right place to put it in or should it go in the html file?

You can create a document in a particular folder, let me update the answer to include that.

Does the code you sent go in the code.gs or index.html?

Yes, paste the code inside the Code.gs file. If you crate the script from a Google Form I will find the Active Form. I can create a repo if you need more help. I've updated the post again with some screenshots

If you run the script for the first time, you need to run the code manually in order to give the script authorization to use Google Docs and Google Drive

I did authorize access to both things. But I'm not using Google Forms. I have an HTML form. I think that changes things, right? That form then saves the data into a google sheets. I can send you the code or you can check out the form. This is the link to my form:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5j0XsiiBrt8YjyzkvgKFusU9IxpChSEjO3unZ7ASktwH0QEM5xSNyjkBJQ0qII2G5/exec

No problem, you still need to add the code inside Code.gs. After you save tha data into the spreadsheet yo can create the doc and add paragraphs with the values from the submition

I've updated my answer. You can use that code as an example. An you should iterate your reponse in order to write paragraphs on the Document

would you mind simplifying it even more for me? Besides pasting in the code you wrote, not sure what changes I'm supposed to make.

Yes, no problem. The code snippet I left in the answer does 3 things: 1 - Define an array with mock data. 2- Creates a new Google Doc file and 3 - Writes that document with the values from the array. I think you must follow the same steps in your script. Where in the process do you think I can provide you with more support?

Maybe if you can make a copy of your script in a repository without showing sentive information, I can edit it.

Totally new to this...but how would I send the script? Can I share the google sheets?

No problem. This is my google account fellowstack@gmail.com

Shared it with you!! Thank you
